# How to use replace function with Angular?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, regex

I am trying to do a simple two way binding but checking and updating the input text if it contains two word strings. For example if the input is "Comedy Movies" then

`Comedy Movies ----> comedy_movies`

I did this through jQuery like

```
var str = $('#item').val()
if (str.match(/^[a-z\.]+ [a-z]+/i)) {
  str = str.replace(/\s+/g, '_').toLowerCase();
}
```

But not sure how to do it through angular. How can I fix this?

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app>
    Item:
    <input type="text" ng-model="name" id="item"/>
      <br />
      <br />
    <div>{{name}}</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can *bind* using `ng-bind` of a function that contains you code - see a demo below:

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('ctrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.name = 'Comedy Movies';

  $scope.getString = function() {
    var str = $scope.name;
    if (str.match(/^[a-z\.]+ [a-z]+/i)) {
      str = str.replace(/\s+/g, '_').toLowerCase();
    }
    return str;
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  Item:
  <input type="text" ng-model="name" id="item" />
  <br />
  <br />
  <div ng-bind="getString()"></div>
</div>
```